# Why does declaring a variable in console produce undefined as output?

Tags: javascript, console

the following codes are input and output in javascript console:

```
Input:"hello";
Output:"hello"
Input: js="hello";
Output: hello
Input:let js="hello";
Output: undefined
```

Please explain how the values are being returned?

Comment: You should post your exact complete code. Input to what? Output from what?

Comment: @TG [The browser's console](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/javascript/).

Comment: As TG suggest is to post your code that render this console log.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is being *returned*, but expressions *resolve* to a value.  *Statements* however do not resolve to a value.  What you're seeing here is the difference between the two.

A literal value is an expression, it resolves to itself:

```
"hello"
```

Since it's an expression it can be used in place anywhere a value is needed.  For example:

```
if (x == "hello")
```

An assignment operation is also an expression, it resolves to the value being assigned:

```
js = "hello"
```

This can *also* be used in place anywhere a value is needed.  For example:

```
if (x == (js = "hello"))
```

The result of that `if` condition would be assigning a value to the variable `js` *and* checking if `x` equals that value.

However, *declaring* a variable is not an expression.  It's a statement.  So this does *not* resolve to a value:

```
let js = "hello"
```

As a result it *can not* be used in place anywhere a value is needed.  Since it's a statement, it has to exist as its own operation.

The output you're seeing in the console is simply the printed value that your code resolved to.  The statement doesn't resolve to a value, so the console prints `undefined`.

Comment: I think it's kind of inaccurate statements do not return a value. If you evaluate a statement you do get a value out of it and these could all very well be statements.